# Django website is an application required?

Tags: python, django

I am using Django to create a website and was wondering should I just create a single application to store the website in or would I put all Django files(views.py, urls.py, etc.) in the Projects root directory and not worry about making an application? I noticed when I run the server I have to use the ip/application-name as the URL to get to my website and was wondering how I could just use the ip instead.

Comment: Create an application, a lot of the Django magic is based on applications and even **if** get your stuff working without applications you would miss a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to prefix the url with the application name.

Say, for example, that you are following the Polls tutorial. Instead of prefixing all of the polls urls like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^otherapp/', include('otherapp.urls')),

    ...
```

you can drop the prefix

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('otherapp.urls')),
```

Be careful if you do this, your urls from different apps might now clash.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create an application. You don't need to care about where are your files, and the `/application` url is not really necessary, just configure the site urls at the `urls.py` and you are ok.

I would suggest you to follow the tutorials at the Django documentation, to understand how Django works:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I have gone through the tutorial and ended up updating my projects urls.py so i didn't have to add the /application-name portion of the url. Was just unsure on what was the best practice. It seems that people are saying making an application for the site is considered best practice.

Comment: Yes, this is the best pratice, you get your files organized and the most important thing to know about is that they can be reusable, if you follow the best pratices you can create other sites using the same applications.